# Inject immutable list with Spring util:list

Tags: java, spring, code-injection

I am using `util:list` tag in my XML Spring config file. How can I make it this list immutable before injecting it to other beans?

I want to do it directly using `util:list` if possible, I do not want to do it for each bean to avoid duplicated code.

Comment: Show some code. How are you using things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
<bean id="unmodifiableCollection"
         class="java.util.Collections" 
         factory-method="unmodifiableList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:list>
            <value>item1</value>
            <value>item2</value>
        </util:list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

it is ugly, but it should create an immutable list